# Using DataBase in android studio, how do I create the DataBase? how do I use it in different Activities?

Tags: android, database, android-studio

I am only at the beginning of my project and I am stack!
This is a school project, I need to create an app that would be able (theoretically) to order from restaurants from far distance, and by that to make it easy to order and pay.
For that I need to use Database, I need to build table for **Products** that the restaurant is suggesting, Table for the different **Categories**, **Users** table and **Reservations** table.
these are the columns in every table:

```
    //product table columns
public static final String PRODUCT_KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String PRODUCT_KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String PRODUCT_KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String PRODUCT_KEY_PRICE= "price";
public static final String PRODUCT_KEY_QUANTITY= "quantity";

//category table columns
public static final String CATEGORY_KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String CATEGORY_KEY_NAME = "name";

//users table columns
public static final String USERS_KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String USERS_KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String USERS_KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String USERS_KEY_MAIL = "mail";

//reservation table columns
public static final String RESERVATION_KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String RESERVATION_KEY_USERID = "user";
public static final String RESERVATION_KEY_PRICE = "price";
public static final String RESERVATION_KEY_PAID = "is_it_paid";
```

How can I build my Database so that *every Activity* will be able to access it after first created?
**Edit:**I have already created the "CREATE_TABLE_NAME" that it is the String that sends to the SQL.

I am having troubles to implement the onCreate of the DataBase file in the Main class. also I need to save my data somehow so I will have access to it from another activity (update the Database and read from it).

thanks alot and sorry for the long question. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "Main Class"? The way that I mentioned in my answer is possible from every fragment or activities etc. You can perform all operations on the `database` Object from my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the API docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). The example gives you a nice class design that you can follow.
A short summary:

- make your class a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`
- override `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)`
- perform your `sql create statement` on the `db`

You can access it everywhere with your context from e.g. a fragment or activities:

```
// Create an instance of your SQLiteOpenHelper Subclass (in this case YourDB)
YourDB yourDB = new YourDB(this); // the parameter here is a context. (see the API example) 
SQLiteDatabase database = yourDB.getReadableDatabase(); // or: yourDB.getWriteableDatabse() for insert/delete/ update operations.
// do your stuff with the database
// ....
// and remember to close them:
yourDB.close();
database.close();
```

The Android runtime won't create a complete new database if you create a new object.

Comment: first of all thanks, how can I save the context so I will be able to use it again?

Comment: In fragments or activities there's no need to save the context! Your activity inherits from `android.content.ContextWrapper` so you can simply call `this` in the call above. Fragments have the method `getActivity()` which returns the associated activity - so you have another subclass of `ContextWrapper`, which is another valid context.

Comment: so my Main activity onCreate shuold look like this:<br/>
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {<br/>
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);<br/>
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);<br/>

        DBData dbData = new DBData(this);<br/>
    }<br/>

and using this in another activity should look like this:<br/>
DBData dbData = new DBDate(getCallingActivity());  ?

Comment: Nope, you can use the same code in all your activities.`DBData dbData = new DBData(this);`works across all subclasses of `ContextWrapper` or `Context`. Inserts, updates and deletes are immediately visible after the operation or your commit.